# Is it possible to update text in Mura search bar form

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I am working on a Spanish website. I would like to update the text from the search bar from English to Spanish.

Currently, the Search Bar is in English (refer to image below):

[image]

I was able to locate the search form cfm file (it is done in coldfusion):

```
<cfoutput>
    <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" class="#this.searchFormClass#" role="search">
        <#variables.$.getHeaderTag('subHead1')#>
            <label for="search">#variables.$.rbKey('search.search')#</label>
        </#variables.$.getHeaderTag('subHead1')#>
        <div class="#this.searchFormInputWrapperClass#">
            <input type="text" name="Keywords" id="txtKeywords" class="#this.searchFormInputClass#" value="#HTMLEditFormat($.event('keywords'))#" placeholder="#variables.$.rbKey('search.search')#">
            <span class="#this.searchFormSubmitWrapperClass#">
                <button type="submit" class="#this.searchFormSubmitClass#">
                    #$.rbKey('search.search')#
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="display" value="search">
        <input type="hidden" name="newSearch" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="noCache" value="1">
    </form>
</cfoutput>
```

However, I am not sure if I can update the code above by just adding the text? Or, if I would need to locate the what the variable "rbKey" is located and manipulate the output?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mura supports localization which is where you can specify items like this in order to support multiple languages.  This would be the best route as it wouldn't be hard coded to just one language and is already implemented for you.

Check out this resource and consider using the localization tools that are already available and then all your Mura items can be in any language you wish.

https://docs.getmura.com/v7/mura-developers/mura-rendering/internationalization-localization/

Comment: I am currently working with 6.2 and have considered to upgrade but not an option at this time